# How to Use String value in Highchart Series

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

When i tried to pass the string value(data) to highchart series, it return blank chart. How to use the String value in series in highchart jquery plugin.

```
var data="{name: 'Jane',data: [1, 0, 4]},{name: 'John',data: [5, 7, 3]},{name: 'RAHUL',    data: [1, 5, 4]}";

$('#container').highcharts({
 chart: {
     type: 'bar'
 },
 title: {
     text: 'Fruit Consumption'
 },
 xAxis: {
     categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
 },
 yAxis: {
     title: {
         text: 'Fruit eaten'
     }
 },
 series:[data]
```

});

Note: the data will be passed as dynamic.

Check this : http://jsfiddle.net/prathi89/FDjq7/26/

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: @ArtyomNeustroev: i tried converting string to JSON but its not working, `series: JSON.parse(data)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSON.parse()` is not working for you as your data is not a valid JSON string.

There is a trick, however, to force JavaScript to parse that kind of strings:

```
var data="{name: 'Jane',data: [1, 0, 4]},{name: 'John',data: [5, 7, 3]},{name: 'RAHUL',    data: [1, 5, 4]}";
console.log(Function("return [" + data + "];")());
```

This is not clean and considered harmful, so if you can get your data in a valid JSON format - do it instead.

http://jsfiddle.net/neustroev_ai/FDjq7/27/